# How to convert JSON to node.js object

Tags: json, node.js, object, dictionary

I have a JSON tree like this that is being posted to my node.js (we'll call it message for the sake of this question):

```
var message = ["layer1": [
                     "color": "Blue",
                     "size": "small",
                     "layer2": [
                         "item1": "TEST"
                     ]
                  ]
              ]
```

How can I make it so I can access individual nodes and values in node.js,   something like this:

```
var sample1 = message.layer1
var sample2 = message.layer1.layer2.item1
```

if I were to `console.log(sample1)` it would look like this:

```
["color": "Blue",
 "size": "small",
 "layer2": [
     "item1": "TEST"
     ]
]
```

and `console.log(sample2)` would look like this:

`"TEST"`

Is this possible?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(jsonString)`.

Comment: What is your question? Yes, you can write `message.layer1.layer2.item1`, and yes, it will evaluate to `"TEST"`. What do you mean a "JSON tree" being "posted" to your "node.js"? Is your question about how to handle the POST, if that's what it is, and/or how to store it into, and/or retrieve it from, a database?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `message` variable is not Javascript (your `message` seems to be an array, but have `key:value`, which is not allowed in Javascript).

You have to replace "`[`" by "`{`" and "`]`" by "`}`" in your `message` to have a Javascript object. Then your `sample1` and `sample2` variables should work.